# Scala - "pattern matching results in loosened type guarantees"?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-inference

Out of [a paper](http://scalamacros.org/news/2013/04/22/let-our-powers-combine.html) by Eugene Burmako:

> In Akka, a [...], actors typically interact using an untyped `tell` method. Since actors are able to send messages of arbitrary types to one another, type information is lost on the receiver side, and can typically only be recovered using **pattern matching, loosening type guarantees**.

What guarantees is he referring to, here, and why does pattern matching weaken them?

Answer (score 4):

A Spoty Spot's answer tells you what guarantees are lost, but the answer for "why does pattern matching weaken them" is that it doesn't. You misparsed the sentence slightly. Instead of

> **pattern matching, loosening type guarantees**

read it as

> **type information is lost on the receiver side**, and can typically only be recovered using pattern matching, **loosening type guarantees**

"and can typically only be recovered..." is a [parenthetical](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/parenthetical).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple akka example (from: [here](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/simple-scala-akka-actor-examples-hello-world-actors))

```
import akka.actor._

class HelloActor(myName: String) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case "hello" => println("hello from %s".format(myName))
    case _       => println("'huh?', said %s".format(myName))
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("HelloSystem")
  val helloActor = system.actorOf(Props(new HelloActor("Fred")), name ="helloactor")
  helloActor ! "hello"
  helloActor ! "buenos dias"
}
```

The receive function in the HelloActor takes an Any type. (Technically it is a partial function from Any to Unit). This means to understand its type we need to pattern match. I could send an Int to the HelloActor and the compiler wouldn't stop me. If I simply had a normal function that took in a string then the compiler would detect that. This lack of type safety is what I believe the quote is referring to.

There are typed akka actors but I have never used them and am not sure what they entail.